# Bootstrap 5 columns with even space between them but first and last item to the edge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know how to create five columns in bootstrap, but this centers the items in the container and the first and last item are a couple of pixels from the container edge. How can I make sure the container is fully filled with 5 items?

My code is now like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">content</div>
<div class="col-md-2">content</div>
<div class="col-md-2">content</div>
<div class="col-md-2">content</div>
<div class="col-md-2">content</div>
```

Example:

Text at the same position as the boxes:

[image]

But then I make 5 boxes out of them and they change position (centered):

[image]

Comment: Are they placed in a `<div class="row">`?

Comment: All Bootstrap columns i.e. `col-xs-*`, `.col-sm-*` etc etc. must be wrapped in `.row`.

Comment: Yeah the code is all correct. I'm just asking how to have it full width.

Comment: Please put an image of what you want to be.